# Two different idle (python) versions installed, none of them work properly

Tags: python, ubuntu, conda, windows-subsystem-for-linux, python-idle

I downloaded WSL for windows because I needed some modules that are not yet suited for Windows. Thus, I downloaded conda, and all the packages I needed in an environment. It seems that I accidently installed two versions of python 3.10.12 and 3.11.4. The first one seems to be the one in wsl, and works well if it wasn't for the fact that it's not able to get all the packages I need. The latter, on the other hand, opens everything, but I cannot modify the font, which is very small and it is difficult to read.
To call them I simply type "idle" for the first one, and "idle3" or "python -m idlelib" for the second one.
What I was thinking is that maybe one of the two versions is seen as "the official one" so that all the changes (fontsize, font, indentation etc.) go to that version (the first one), but, again, it's not able to see the installed packages. So I was wondering if it makes sense to unistall it. However, when I open the path for the first version, it turns out that it is the one that comes with WSL.
I am sorry if I wrote something in a not so clear way, but I am not an expert as you can see and I may refer to something using wrong terms. I hope the picture is more or less clear.
I attach images for both idle shells if that can help [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iu8uR.png)

I tried to apply other suggestions from previously posted questions: see if the paths of the packages and the idle shell are the same (no but I don't know how to fix it); try to manually add configuration to the small-sized-font idle to modify the font (did not work).

Comment: IDLE as released by the core developers normally stores configuration files in a `.idlerc` directory in the users home directory, as defined by `os.path.expanduser('~')`.  If not available, it tries the current directory.  See `idlelib/config.py` `IdleConf.GetUserCfgDir` for the code.  Try `import os; os.path.expanduser('~')` in each IDLE Shell and then check that/those directory/ies. The font should be in config_main.cfg. I cannot tell what you did to try to change the font.  One must be very exact in such questions.

Comment: I did as you suggested, and both idel shells gave me '/home/user'. Then, I went to the home directory with 'cd /home' and in user, but I only find the following: Anaconda3-2022.05-Linux-x86_64.sh  Untitled.ipynb   miniconda3       snap
Anaconda3-5.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh    anaconda3

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It has been over 20 years since I used unix, but I believe you need to pass an option flag to the file lister (`ls`?) to see filesnames beginning with `.`.

Comment: Hello. I finally found .idlerc and config-main.cfg. The problem is that if I change the font there, the idle shell that gets modified is the one that is not able to open the packages I want (astropy, scipy, matplotlib.pyplot, and others). By using os.path.expanduser('~'), both idles are in /home/user, so I don't know how to "refer" the changes to the idle I want to work (the one with the required packages).